# Cassandra frequent read time out errors

Tags: exception, timeout, cassandra

I am new to cassandra just knows basics of it. I am facing frequent exceptions in cassandra. I'm using the thrift API single node cassandra. Mainly I am doing writes but those involves existing check.

I tried increasing `read_request_timeout_in_ms` from 10s to a very large no: 9480secs. Then also i got timeout errors. I do not know exact reason behind this.

Here is stacktrace :

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out    
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFastFramedTransport.readFrame(TFastFramedTransport.java:140)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFastFramedTransport.read(TFastFramedTransport.java:134)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_set_keyspace(Cassandra.java:531)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.set_keyspace(Cassandra.java:518)
    at  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out  

    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: You should reformat your dump. Your gestion is more likely to be answered when formatted well and readable

Comment: @user2572801 By frequent do you mean like 1/5 or do you mean every request?

Comment: not very request after many inserts it start breaking

Answer (score 4):

What's going on here is that you've told Cassandra to let your queries run for a long time, but you haven't told your Thrift client to wait that long for a reply from Cassandra.

But really, 10s is plenty of time.  Don't change that.  Instead, figure out why your queries are taking longer with tracing: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tracing-in-cassandra-1-2

Additionally, you should check out the data modeling resources here: https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DataModel.  Existance-check-before-write is a design smell.

Comment: yes i need to try some monitoring tools.. will give a try.. as i am newbie one dumb question :  i have one table rel which stores 3 columns having 3 ids..... rel table (rowkey, startId, relId, endId)..all three are indexed as lookup can be by either of them..right now rowkey is UUID...so existing check i have to do before any insert..can i avoid this by designing rowkey as hash of these 3 ids so that i do not have to do existing check...is this right design...

Comment: Could you elaborate Existance-check-before-write is a design smell or link some resources related to that?